# How to remove first word from a string?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm looking for the best way to remove the first word from a `std::string`. This is what I have but I feel that this is overcompilicating things. What's the best and shortest way to do this? Thanks.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string str{"Where is everybody?"};
    std::string first;
    if (std::stringstream{str} >> first)
    {
        str.erase(str.begin(), str.begin() + first.size());
    }
    std::cout << str; // " is everybody?"
}
```

Comment: That won't even work if the `str` has a space at the beginning: you will still read a word with 5 letters, and end up with "e is everybody?". Why don't you just make a loop to find the first non-space character, then another loop to find the next space.

Comment: @riv Instead of using a loop, just use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) with [`std::isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) as the predicate, and the find again to find the first non-space.

Comment: @riv Would that be the best and fastest way?

Comment: First you need to define what a 'word' is.  Is it a sequence of letters?  Or letters and digits?  What about punctuation?  What's the first word of this sentence -- "What" or "What's"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

minor tweak, that leverages IO streams for the second half too :)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string str{"Where is everybody?"};

    std::string first;
    std::istringstream iss{str};
    iss >> first;

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << iss.rdbuf();

    std::cout << oss.str(); // " is everybody?"
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'std::istringstream iss(str)' instead of 'std::istringstream iss{str}'?

Comment: @PolGraphic Depends on your compiler. C++11 allows both (uniform initialization)

Answer (score 6):

You can do it without a stream: skip the initial spaces, locate the first space after that, walk to the next non-space, and use `substr` to get the rest of the `string`:

```
int i = 0;
while (isblank(str[i])) i++;
while (!isblank(str[i])) i++;
while (isblank(str[i])) i++;
str = str.substr(i);
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/s6digP).

Comment: You've got that backwards. Try adding a space in front of your input string.  http://ideone.com/Jhh1HV

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You're right, the "skip blanks" loop should be on both sides (in case there's more than one space after the word as well). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using c++11's regex

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

int main ()
{
  std::string s ("there is a subsequence in the string\n");
  std::regex e ("(\\s*)(\\w*)(.*)");
  std::cout << std::regex_replace (s,e,"$1$3");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: i used clang not every compiler has support for c++11 regex, I really couldn't help you here I never use ideone

Comment: GCC's C++11 regex implementation is broken.

Comment: that would explain it just use clang

Comment: I supposed whoever downvoted thinks gcc's broken regex is my fault

Comment: I'd rather expect the downvoter to think that your dismissive attitude was uncalled for. People don't get to pick their compilers  on a whim, or because _someone on the internet shrugged_. That all said, it's not even a compiler feature in the first place.

Comment: @not-sehe, actually they downvoted before I said anything, and your right that people don't always get to pick their compilers but I don't think that means I should delete my correct answer when the question says nothing specific about compilers

Answer (score 1):

You could try using string::substr() and string::find_first_of().